# ReferenceFields with MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongoengine

I'm playing with MongoEngine and i can't find the way querying ReferenceFields

```
class UserAccount(Document):
    name = StringField()

class UserGroup(Document):
    name = StringField()
    accounts = ListField(ReferenceField(UserAccount))

    group = UserGroup.objects(name='SomeName').first()
```

I have many UserAccounts and UserGroups with these accounts.
I'm trying to get list of accounts which already in the group:

```
accounts_in_group = group.accounts
```

and which are not in this group:

```
accounts_not_in_group = UserAccount.objects(_id__nin=group.accounts)
```

It doesn't work

```
ValidationError: UserAccount object is not a valid ObjectId
```

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use list of `UserAccount` models as a list of `ObjectId`s, which obviously fails. Before making query you need to transform list of models into list of ids, for example using list comprehension:

```
account_ids = [item.pk for item in group.accounts]
accounts_not_in_group = UserAccount.objects(_id__nin=account_ids)
```